# Computing $\int\limits_{p}^{1}\Phi^{-1}(u)\text{ d}u$, $p \in [0, 1]$.

Tags: probability, integration

I need to show that

$$\int\limits_{p}^{1}\Phi^{-1}(u)\text{ d}u = \phi\left[\Phi^{-1}(p)\right]\text{,}$$

where $\phi$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution and $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. That is, if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, 
\begin{align*}
&\phi(z) = f_{Z}(z) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2} \\
&\Phi(z) = F_{Z}(z) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{z}f_{Z}(t)\text{ d}t\text{, }\quad -\infty < z < \infty\text{.} 
\end{align*}
However, I have no idea how to proceed from that integral above, mainly because I can't think of a closed-form expression for $\Phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Hint: Substitute $u=\Phi(t) \Rightarrow du=\phi(t)dt$. The integral is now:

$$
\int_{\Phi^{-1}(p)}^\infty \! t\phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: Nice. I would assume I'd have to integrate by parts from here?

Comment: Sometimes $\int$ by parts works from a similar scenario. Try and see why not here.

Comment: Yep, integration by parts does not look like it will work. Any hints as to how I can get the form I want?

Comment: Write the integral with the definition of $\phi$ explicitly.

Comment: -sigh- I should have done that! I didn't think to do that for some reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $u=\Phi(t) \Rightarrow du=\phi(t)dt$. The integral is now:

$$
\int_{\Phi^{-1}(p)}^\infty \! t\phi(t) dt
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Phi^{-1}(p)}^\infty \!te^{-t^2/2}dt\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(\Phi^{-1}(p))^2/2}^\infty \!e^{-v}dv\\
\qquad \qquad = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\Phi^{-1}(p))^2}\\
\qquad = \phi(\Phi^{-1}(p))
$$